# Did normal Linux upgrades; now boots to emergency mode: how to diagnose?

Tags: linux, updates, reboot

The question is/are: what went wrong and how can I fix it?

I just now did a normal upgrade of my Xubuntu 18.04 system, expecting next to go to 20.04, but now it boots to emergency mode, and I have no idea how to tell why.  I can get to a root login, but cannot get the display server going. If I ever do get it going, you'll be able to access http://kosmanor.com again.

I have created a Google Drive directory with all my clues:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lYcxYlngctRWKWWVKdFTeuemu6TVfXNM?usp=sharing

Contents are

1. Photo of screen on first reboot
2. Photo of screen on second reboot (slightly more output)
3. Script file of the entire update (fortunately, I created bash aliases and scripts to make this easy and I do it every time.)  The only things that look like errors really aren't.  I've set TERM=dumb to make the script catch everything, and the updates note this, but it doesn't matter much because I run with --assume-yes.  The top of the output is the contents of the script that I invoked; the rest is the output from running it, all under script(1) and then processed by col -b.
4. The output of the command suggested by the photos of screens above.  Nothing sticks out to me, but I really don't know how to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I continued to fiddle with it, and found that one of the last lines during a boot attempt had a partial UUID.  This turned out to be the key: the UUID belonged to a USB stick I had been working with, including changing /etc/fstab.  To make a long story shorter, I found that the "noauto" was missing from that line of /etc/fstab, and when it was restored, (or when the stick was actually present during boot), all was well.  Consider case closed.

The answer was: "keep looking, for any detail that might be a hint, then fix it"